# Typescript array.from(iterator) incorrect type and cannot be cast?

Tags: arrays, typescript, iterator

In converting flow code to typescript an error happens when using iterators. The iterator is missing something

```
const iter: Iterator<RouteData> = contentMap.routes();
const contentArray: Array<RouteData> = Array.from(iter);
```

It gives the following error, notice that this points to the *second* line, so `iter` is of correct type/the return of `contentMap.routes()` is an iterator:

```
Error:(109, 55) TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable<RouteData> | ArrayLike<RouteData>): RouteData[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Iterator<RouteData, any, undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<RouteData> | ArrayLike<RouteData>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'Iterator<RouteData, any, undefined>' but required in type 'ArrayLike<RouteData>'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(arrayLike: ArrayLike<RouteData>): RouteData[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Iterator<RouteData, any, undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<RouteData>'.
```

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

The iterator is created somewhere like:

```
routes():Iterator<RouteData> {
    return this._routes.values();
}
```

The compile target for typescript is "es6", so maps should be fully supported? Or is it just impossible to create an array from an iterator and have I been doing it all wrong (and was babel just that forgiving)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, an *iterator* is an object with a `next` method used for iterating through an *iterable* (an object with a `[Symbol.iterator]` method for getting an iterator from it).

`Array.from` accepts an *iterable* (or an array-like), but in that code it thinks it's just getting an *iterator*.

Most iterators, including all of the ones you get from standard JavaScript methods, are also iterable because they implement `[Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }`, directly or indirectly through the iterator prototype —but not all do. So it's not safe to assume that all iterators are iterable.

You probably want to update `routes` to show that it returns something that's both an iterator *and* iterable:

```
routes(): Iterator<T> & Iterable<T> {
    return this._routes.values();
}
```

Then:

```
const iter = contentMap.routes();
const contentArray = Array.from(iter);
```

(There's no need for the explicit types on those, TypeScript will infer them.)

[Here's a version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukAicxzIDeAUMucgM5iYwwBcVYUoA5gNwkC+JJCANnEqVkAYXTgI4ALJwADgB4AKgD5iZCgH0oWSJUazF1FiFYAaZKs4VkCCccwIw6KAAoAlOps2wAC2CUAHTauhAiALzIIBAA7siGCsZsFqoe1hQ8GuQ62GEejACSkFD4LspqXt7ZEDRQIMh+AcE5eoEAbnD8mHnu6eQ8mXYg1LYSkDLyyJHRceKSE4oYuXgEKmm8QyPAxVOj82CGgS09nJtge+NgAIJQJQCeuzf3gTA6ALau29C9JEA) on the playground demonstrating the problem using `Iterator`.

[Here's that same code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukAicxzIDeAUMucgM5iYwwBcVYUoA5gNwkC+JJCANnEqVkAYXTgI4ALJwADgB4AKgD5iZCgH0oWSJUazF1FiFYAaZKs4VkCCccwIw6KAAoAlOps2wAC2CUAHTauhAiALzIIBAA7siGCsZsFqoe1hQ8GuQ62GEejACSkFD4LspqAGTIRdBwAEb8EOXkpN4UUBA0UCDIfgHBOXqBAG5w-Jh57unkPJl2INS2EpAy8siR0XHikquKGLl4BCppvPOLwMXrSztghoGDk5xnYNcrYACCUCUAnlefP4EYDoALauC7QKYkIA) using `Iterator<T> & Iterable<T>` as above.

Comment: FWIW, I go into a fair bit of detail about iterators and iterables in Chapter 6 of my new book out in a couple of months. If you're interested, see my profile for details.

Comment: If I inspect the code in javascript `map.values()` *does* return an object with `next()`: exactly an iterator. EDIT: ok now that I removed all type information I notice typescript automatically assigns it `IterableIterator` type. Begs the question, are any iterators not iterable themselves?

Comment: @paul23 - Yeah, I was just realizing -- you'vre using `values` on what I assume is a `Map`, and that returns an (iterable) iterator. But `Array.from` is defined as taking an *iterable*, not an *iterator*. Again, most iterators (including all you get from built-in JavaScript functions) are also *iterable*, but not all are. So you may want to adjust the return type of `routes`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @paul23 - Fixed it now, sorry for missing the `values` thing (despite having copied it!) on the first pass. :-)